# List of Office Outlook 2010 add-ins

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook-addin

Is there a list of available Office Outlook 2010 Outlook Add-ins somewhere?

Although I've googled before asking this question, I was unable to find a list of add-ins. (I'm probably not looking for the correct keywords)

Comment: Will be in Microsoft App Store soon I believe

Answer (score 5):

You are probably not going to find a comprehensive list, but you can find links to ones that people compile and feel are the best:

http://email.about.com/od/outlookaddons/tp/most_popular_outlook_add_ons.htm

http://www.techsupportalert.com/Best-free-outlook-add-in.htm

I Googled "outlook 2010 add-ins" and "outlook 2010 add-ins best" (both minus the quotes).

Are you looking for one in particular?

Comment: Thanks for posting. I'm looking for a nice spam solution in particular. I'd like to add senders and perform a "move all mails to spam folder"-action. As far as I've looked, I can't find the "move all ..."-action in Outlook 2010

Comment: @citronas I am not sure what you want to be moved to the SPAM folder, current spam you already received, or all future spam. What do you mean by "move all"? From where?

Comment: current spam, that is still located in my inbox

Comment: This question has really been answered. It looks like you should ask another question: Is there a SPAM filtering product for Outlook that will process e-mail that was already received, and is already in the Inbox" (I am not sure if there is one, but maybe someone knows).